# How to remove Clear:Both in CSS

Tags: css

I have the follow CSS --

```
.item {
    clear: both
}
```

Is there a way to remove this downstream. I want to be able to do something like:

```
#div .item {
    clear: remove;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
clear: none;
```

That should do the trick!

That's the initial/default value. See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear